# How to preserve transparency of a png when rotating with GD on e.g. 120 deg?

Tags: php, rotation, png, transparency, gd

Here is the image that I'm trying to rotate

http://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/arrow-point-to-right_32213

Here is the code which gives perfect transparency if rotated Nx90 deg, but as soon as i rotate it to e.g. 170 or 120 deg i get a black frame... How can i get all transparent background?

```
$filename = 'arrow487.png';

$degrees = 170;

 $png = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
$transparency = imagecolorallocatealpha( $png,0,0,0,127 );


$rotated = imagerotate( $png, $degrees, $transparency, 1);

imagealphablending( $rotated, false );

imagesavealpha( $rotated, true );

ob_end_clean();

header( 'Content-Type: image/png' );
imagepng( $rotated );
```